# R function to divide a character vector into prefix + string if the prefix is present

Tags: r, string, split

I have a character vector like this:

`id <-c("A01A01", "A01B01", "A01C01", "R", "S", "T")`

I need to cut a prefix from all the strings that contains it, keeping all the substrings
My expected output are then 2 other vectors like these:

`a <-c("A01", "A01", "A01", "", "", "")`

`b <-c("A01", "B01", "C01", "R", "S", "T")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sub` like:

```
sub("^(A01).*|.*", "\\1", id)
#[1] "A01" "A01" "A01" ""    ""    ""   

sub("^A01", "", id)
#[1] "A01" "B01" "C01" "R"   "S"   "T"
```

where `^(A01).*|.*` matches `A01` in the beginning or everything and `\\1` inserts `A01` if it matches.

Another option would be a look behind in `strsplit`.

```
strsplit(id, "(?<=^A01)", perl=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
a <- sapply(id, function(x) if(nchar(x)%%2 == 0) substr(x, 1,nchar(x)/2) else '', USE.NAMES = FALSE)
b <- sapply(id, function(x) if(nchar(x)%%2 == 0) substr(x,nchar(x)/2+1, nchar(x)) else x,USE.NAMES = FALSE)
a
[1] "A01" "A01" "A01" ""    ""    ""   
b
[1] "A01" "B01" "C01" "R"   "S"   "T"
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
tibble(id) %>% 
   extract(id, into = c('a', 'b'), '(A01)?(.*)')
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  a     b    
  <chr> <chr>
1 "A01" A01  
2 "A01" B01  
3 "A01" C01  
4 ""    R    
5 ""    S    
6 ""    T
```